# Question on rules of conditional probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

This is a somewhat trivial question, but I can't find anything anywhere to tell me how to solve it.

I have the values of the following:

```
P(A|B)
P(C|A)
P(C|not A)
P(A)
```

I need to find `P(A|B,C)`

I know that `P(A,B|C) = P(A|C) P(B|C)`

Would it also be correct to assume

`P(A|B,C) = P(A|B) P(A|C)` ?

since I already have `P(A|B)` and can easily derive `P(A|C)` using the information I have (bayes theorem).

(We also know the B and C occuring are independent of eachother)

Comment: The data does not suffice to compute `P(A|B,C)`.

Answer (score 0):

Per Bay’s Rule
$$P( A B C ) = P( B C ) * P( A | B C ) = P( B C | A ) * P( A )$$
$$P( A | B C ) = \frac{ P( B C | A ) * P( A ) }{ P( B C )}$$
**Assuming** B and C are conditionally independent on A
$$P( A | B C )  = \frac{ P( B | A ) * P( C | A ) * P( A )}{P( B ) * P( C )}$$
Also per Bay’s
$$P( B | A ) = \frac{P( A | B ) * P( B )}{P( A )}$$
So
$$P( A | B C ) = \frac{ P( A | B ) * P( B ) * P( C | A ) * P( A )}{ P( A ) * P( B ) * P( C )} $$
Cancelling
$$P( A | B C ) = \frac{ P( A | B ) * P( C | A )}{ P( C )} $$
Rewriting P( C )
$$P( A | B C ) = \frac{ P( A | B ) * P( C | A )}{ P( C | A ) + P( C | \overline{A} )} $$

Comment: "Since B and C are independent ... P( BC | A )  = P( B | A ) P( C | A )" This is frankly wrong, because independence does not imply conditional independence. Counterexamples abound and are customarily given in first courses on stochastic independence.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I did assume conditional independence as well.  If that is not the case, then it is wrong.  @BKS, can you clarify?